# Plot[] breaks behavior of custom data handling function - Recursion

Tags: functions, data

I am working on a utility to analyze a set of data.  I want to process the data with a sliding window, in such a way that there is an output associated with each sample of data.

To start, I have a list of data: `MyData`

I've defined the following utility function to pull 10 consecutive samples of data from  `MyData` starting at an arbitrary location within `MyData`.

```
EvalWin[x_] := Take[MyData, {x, x + 9}];
```

This works.

Now lets say I have a processing function that sums the 10 samples.

```
ProcData[x_] := Total[EvalWin[x]];
```

This also works.

The problem comes if I attempt to use `ProcData[]` as an argument to a built in Mathematica function such as `Plot`.

For example if I attempt to plot `ProcData[]` for a set of 100 samples...

```
Plot[ProcData[x], {x, 10, 110}]
```

The `Plot` function blows up due to recursion.

Are there ways to control how built in functions handle data to avoid recursive blow up, or is there a more Mathematica friendly way to accomplish this kind of data manipulation?

Comment: Your problem isn't recursion, it's the fact that array indices have to be positive integers and `Plot` assumes a continuous variable.

Comment: By the way, in case you're really interested in something like what your example does, maybe take a look at [MovingAverage](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MovingAverage.html)

Answer (score 7):

Use [`DiscretePlot[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DiscretePlot.html) instead for **integer-valued** functions:

```
ProcData[x_Integer] := Sum[MyData[[k]], {k, x, x + 9}]

DiscretePlot[ProcData[x], {x, 10, 110, 1}]
```

Comment: This (+1), or `ListPlot` seem to be the most appropriate solutions. Or one could stick with `Plot` and replace `ProcData[x]` with `ProcData[Floor[x]]`.

Comment: So the issue is really in the need to establish that I am working with an integer.  Thanks.